# Nestjs: Cannot PUT, Cannot DELETE (404 not found)

Tags: crud, nestjs

I'm on a task to write a simple CRUD program for a users list, following a similar nestjs example. While GET, POST and GET by id works fine, PUT and DELETE does not work properly. I get 'User does not exist' however user exists in database.

**Controller**

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}
.....

//Update a user's details
@Put('/update')
async updateUser(
    @Res() res, 
    @Query('userid') userID, 
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto
) {
    const user = await this.userService.updateUser(userID, createUserDto);
    if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('User does not exist!');
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
        message: 'User has been successfully updated',
        user
    })
}

//Delete a user
@ApiParam({ name: 'id' })
@Delete('/delete')
async deleteUser(@Res() res, @Query('userid') userID) {
    const user = await this.userService.deleteUser(userID);
    if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('Customer does not exist');
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
        message: 'User has been deleted',
        user
    })
}
```

**Service**

```
 // Edit user details
async updateUser(userID, createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const updatedUser = await this.userModel
        .findByIdAndUpdate(userID, createUserDto, { new: true });
    return updatedUser;
}

// Delete a customer
async deleteUser(userID): Promise<any> {
    const deletedUser = await this.userModel
        .findByIdAndRemove(userID);
    return deletedUser; 
}
```

I'm using swagger to perform my tests. I'm passing id as a parameter to find and update user.

Comment: Have you checked the url you are making a call to? Have you tried with Postman or curl? Nest doesn't just not route to the routes you expect unless something is missing. From what;'s shown, that can't be determined

Comment: Thank you Jay for your comment. As far as i understand, the url is ok http://localhost/users/update. I checked with Postman, the same result. Maybe something in the code might be the problem?

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:3000/users/update/<ID>`? You're probably not running on port 80, so `localhost` on its own won't do any good.

Comment: Yes i just did, [http://localhost:3000/users/update/5eaf229ef853437fc2f2d657]. Now i got `"message": "Cannot PUT /users/update/5eaf229ef853437fc2f2d657"`

Comment: Hmm, well, like I said in my first comment, there isn't enough here to see hat's happening. If you have a git repo publicly available I can take a look there

Comment: Yes, sure, thanks. Git repo [https://github.com/paniklas/vilapp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code repository, you aren't using URL Parameters, but rather you are using Query Parameters. The difference in the two is how they are passed to the server and how they are told to the server to listen for them.

## Query Parameters

With query parameters, you pass them to your server starting with a `?` in the url, and concatenating each one after by using a `&`. An example could look something like `http://localhost:3000?name=Test&id=a26408f3-69eb-4443-8af7-474b896a9e70`. Notice that there are two Query parameters, one named `name` and one named `id`. In Nest, to get these parameters in your route handler, you would use the `@Query()` decorator. A sample class could look like

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  getHello(@Query() query: { name: string, id: string }) {
    return `Hello ${name}, your ID is ${id}`;
  }
}
```

Notice how with the url above, the route called is the base route (`/`), with the query parameters added on.

## URL Parameters

URL parameters are a way to dynamically build your routes without needing to specify what each possible URL. This is useful for things like IDs that are dynamically generated. Taking a similar URL as above, the sample URL this time could look like `http://localhost:3000/Test/a26408f3-69eb-4443-8af7-474b896a9e70`. Notice how this time there is no `?` or `&` and it just looks like a full URL. To specify URL Params in nest, you need to a a colon(`:`) before the param name in the resource declaration decorator, along with any other part of the path necessary. Then to access the URL Parameters, you need to use the `@Param()` decorator in the route handler, similar to how you would the `@Query()` decorator. The class sample for this would be

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get(':name/:id')
  getHello(@Param() params: { name: string, id: string })
    return `Hello ${name}, your ID is ${id}`;
  }
}
```

## Problem and Solution

You're currently calling off to `http://localhost/users/update/<ID>` acting as if you are using URL parameters, but in your route handler you are expecting `@Query()` to grab the id. Because of this, there is no handler to find `/users/update/:id` and so you are getting a 404 in return. You can either modify your server to listen for URL Parameters as described above, or you can modify the URL to send the request using Query Parameters instead of URL parameters.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I just followed your instructions and problem solved. I used URL Params instead of @Query decorator. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted if it helped so others can know it's on the right path as well